Only one node generated after using decision tree model on training data set
I am trying to build a decision tree model predicting an outcome variable (named : Results) based on predictor variable. Indeed, I have applied one-hot encoding on some of the ">2 level" variables to enable expanding the n of predictors a bit. I first explored the data and then split it into 80/20 split and run the model, but the model run on training data set ends with only one node with no branches as seen in this figure below.
.
Looking to similar posts, I sought that my data is unbalanced because by checking the prop.table of the class assignation (of the Results variable), the majority was for negative rather than for positive. Any suggestions for creating a correct tree on this data
Here comes my code:
splitting the data into test and train data (80% train and 20% test data)
set.seed(1234)
pd <- sample(2, nrow(data_hum_mod), replace = TRUE, prob = c(0.8,0.2))
data_hum_train <- data_hum_mod[pd==1,]
data_hum_test<- data_hum_mod[pd==2,]

Data exploration after splitting
Check the data dimension
dim(data_hum_train); dim(data_hum_test) #make sure that the spllited data have balanced n of each of the outcome classes (i.e. positive/negative toxo)

prop.table(table(data_hum_train$Results)) * 100
prop.table(table(data_hum_test$Results)) *100

This gave the following results:
# (Train)
Negative Positive 
75.75758 24.24242

# and (Test)

Negative Positive 
54.54545 45.45455

# Check missing values
anyNA(data_hum_mod) 

#Make sure none of the variables are zero or near-zero variance
nzv(data_hum_mod)

# building the model (using party package)

install.packages('party')
library(party)
data_human_train_tree<- ctree(Results ~., data = data_hum_train,
                              controls = ctree_control(mincriterion = 0.1))
data_human_train_tree
plot(data_human_train_tree)

With this code I obtained this figure
It gave me the same results using other packages like C50 and rpart
Could you advise on this? and I read about the subsampling for the majority class (here is the negative Results), how can one implement this in R?

The main problem is probably that you have set mincriterion too high, so that no splits exceed it. Try removing that entirely, or reducing it.
Class imbalance is probably not an issue. But it is a bit concerning that your test set's balance is significantly different from the training set's.
Also, I would suggest "ordinal-encoding" (as integers 1,2,... e.g.) any ordinal variables like age group and education.
